# How to add an attribute to the first select option in twig symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to add a few attributes (f.e. `disabled` and `selected`) to the first option in select tag.

this line `{{ form_widget(form.idkategoria) }}` in twig render:

```
<select id="foo" name="foo">
<option value="">Kategoria</option>
<option value="1">foo</option>
<option value="2">foo</option>
```

---

or how to add an `'attr'` to placeholder to keep default 'Kategoria' text.

```
$builder->add('idkategoria', null, array
                ('placeholder' => 'Kategoria',))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$builder->add('idkategoria', null, ['attr' => ['placeholder' =>'Kategoria']]) ]
```

You can find an extract in the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options-guessing)

Comment: by saying `or how to add an 'attr' to placeholder` I meant adding attribute, f.e. `disabled` or `selected`, to placeholder which is `option` tag. Becouse this line `->add('idkategoria', null, array('placeholder' => 'Kategoria','attr'=> array('required'=>true))` makes `required` a `select` tag, not `option` as I wish (Anyway, I walked the problem in completely different way -css-that is not the answer to my question. You can leave this issue. Thanks)